# Как прочитать список из текстового файла?

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, список

Имеется задача: считать определённые данные в список, загрузить их в текстовый файл, а из него выгрузить список в том же формате.
В списке элемент представлен в формате: ['/faculty/95/groups/24036', '13531/1']
Вот код:

```
for f in b.find_all('a', href=True):
h = f.getText()
g.append( [f['href'],  h])
i= i+1
print ("Found the URL:", f['href'])
with open("groups.txt", "w") as file:
   print(*g, file=file, sep="\n")
file.close()

array = list(open('groups.txt'))
print(array[8])#1
print(array[8][1])#2
print(array)#3
```

Но есть проблема, выгруженный из файла список представляется в неправильном виде, как строка. То есть запись #1 выводит всю восьмую строку, #2 выводит только первый символ восьмой строки, а #3 выводит единой строкой весь файл.

Как сделать так, чтобы можно было выгрузить список в том же виде, в котором он загружался в текстовый файл? Чтобы можно было запись #2 получить именно первый элемент('13531/1'), а не первый символ.

С Питоном работаю мало, после Си прям очень непривычно, поэтому такие вопросы и возникают.

Comment: Если используете with, то не нужно после вызывать `.close`

Comment: лучше использовать слова: читать/писать в отношении текстового файла для ясности (слова выгрузить/загрузить часто в противоположном чем в вашем вопросе смысле используются)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас вложенный список, поэтому простая структура из списка строк для вас не подойдёт иначе код в вопросе уже правильно писал/читал бы список строк:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from pathlib import Path

urls = ['a', 'b', 'c']
path = Path('urls.txt')
path.write_text('\n'.join(urls))      # write list
urls = path.read_text().splitlines()  # read list
```

Файл при этом выглядит как:

```
a
b
c
```

Для списка строк, состоящих из полей, [можно csv формат использовать](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import csv

rows = [['a', 'A'], ['b', 'B'], ['c', 'C']]
with open('urls.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    csv.writer(file).writerows(rows)   # write rows

with open('urls.csv', newline='') as file:
    rows = list(csv.reader(file))      # read rows
```

csv файл выглядит как:

```
a,A
b,B
c,C
```

Для более сложной структуры, представляющей каждый url, можно [json формат использовать](https://json.org):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import json
from pathlib import Path

pages = [
    {'url': 'a', 'id': 1, 'next': [2, 3]},
    {'url': 'b', 'id': 2, 'next': [1, 3]},
    {'url': 'c', 'id': 3, 'next': [1, 2]}
]
path = Path('pages.json')
path.write_text(json.dumps(pages, indent=2), encoding='utf-8')  # write
pages = json.loads(path.read_text(encoding='utf-8'))            # read
```

json файл:

```
[
  {
    "url": "a",
    "id": 1,
    "next": [
      2,
      3
    ]
  },
  {
    "url": "b",
    "id": 2,
    "next": [
      1,
      3
    ]
  },
  {
    "url": "c",
    "id": 3,
    "next": [
      1,
      2
    ]
  }
]
```

Иногда можно каждый элемент на своей строчке писать http://jsonlines.org:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import json

# append page
page = {'url': 'a', 'id': 1, 'next': [2, 3]}
with open('pages.jsonlines', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    print(json.dumps(page), file=file)

# process pages
with open('pages.jsonlines', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    for line in file:
        page = json.loads(line)
        ...
```

файл может выглядеть как:

```
{"url": "a", "id": 1, "next": [2, 3]}
{"url": "b", "id": 2, "next": [1, 3]}
{"url": "c", "id": 3, "next": [1, 2]}
```

Если возникнет желание удалять из середины такого файла, не переписывая его целиком, или искать определённые записи по критериями, не просматривая весь файл, то стоит использовать встроенную базу данных, такую как [sqlite](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) (двоичный формат). В виде sql это выглядит как:

```
CREATE TABLE page (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    url VARCHAR(50), 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
INSERT INTO "page" VALUES(1,'a');
INSERT INTO "page" VALUES(2,'b');
INSERT INTO "page" VALUES(3,'c');
CREATE TABLE association (
    from_id INTEGER, 
    to_id INTEGER, 
    FOREIGN KEY(from_id) REFERENCES page (id), 
    FOREIGN KEY(to_id) REFERENCES page (id)
);
INSERT INTO "association" VALUES(1,3);
INSERT INTO "association" VALUES(2,3);
INSERT INTO "association" VALUES(1,2);
INSERT INTO "association" VALUES(3,2);
INSERT INTO "association" VALUES(2,1);
INSERT INTO "association" VALUES(3,1);
```

Фактически, при использовании ORM такой как sqlalchemy для частых задач нет необходимости sql руками писать. К примеру, заполнение аналогичное приведённому sql может выглядеть как:

```
pages = Page(id=1, url='a'), Page(id=2, url='b'), Page(id=3, url='c')
pages[0].next_pages.extend(pages[1:])
# similar for pages[1], pages[2]...
session.add_all(pages)
```

Пример поиска. Найти страницу с заданным url:

```
page = session.query(Page).filter_by(url='a').one()
print(page)
# -> <Page(id=1, url='a', next_pages=[2, 3])>
```

Найти страницы, ссылающиеся на данную `page`:

```
print(*session.query(Page).filter(Page.next_pages.contains(page)),
      sep='\n')
# -> <Page(id=3, url='c', next_pages=[1, 2])>
# -> <Page(id=2, url='b', next_pages=[1, 3])>
```

Answer (score 2):

Считать список строк из файла можно следующими способами:

**1.**

```
with open('groups.py') as f:
    print(list(f))
```

**2.**

```
with open('groups.py') as f:
    print(f.readlines())
```

**3.**

```
with open('groups.py') as f:
    lines = [line for line in f]
    print(lines)
```

**4.**

```
with open('groups.py') as f:
    lines = []
    
    for line in f:
        lines.append(line)
    
    print(lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно отталкиваться от конструкции, которая у вас на 6 строке:

```
with open('groups.txt') as f:
    my_lines = list(f)
```