# Как расширить модель sqlalhemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Есть модель Person и от неё наследник модель Boss. Я получаю из базы модель Person и мне надо её как то превратить в модель Boss при этом не удаляя саму запись из бд. Как это сделать?

Comment: вы уверены, что вы хотите два разных Питон-класса использовать для одной и той же записи в базе данных? Может лучше завести role отношение (должности) и ассоциацию установить (многие-ко-многим кто какие должности занимает)? ([web-страницы и ссылки между ними (в конце ответа)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/805249/23044))

Answer (score 0):

используя механизм наследования в SQLAlchemy http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/inheritance.html